# How to call the toggle function when I click on the right or left button?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

With this following piece of code in html file which calls the ts file. Need help with calling the toggle function every time a user click on the left or right move button, so the selection can be false.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-listbox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a common function that does the unselection for you, once you move anything or everything.

```js
public moveSelected(direction) {
    // Your existing code here
    this.unselectAll(); // Add this common function
  }

public moveAll(direction) {
    // Your existing code here
    this.unselectAll(); // Add this common function
  }

public unselectAll() { // Use this function as a helper to unselect everything
    this.list1.map((i) => (i.selected = false));
    this.list2.map((i) => (i.selected = false));
  }
```